# Can we set parent element style from child style?

Tags: css

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="sub">
    </div>
</div>
```

Can I set main's style from sub's style?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cascading Stylesheets only go (cascade) down, so they're not designed to do this at all...even in those rare cases it would be *very* handy if they did.

You need either JavaScript, in-line style or a different layout to get the stying you're after...but pure CSS affecting the parent isn't an option here unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This would be possible with Javascript, but not with pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS4 selectors, the original question could be solved with this:

```
li! > a.active { /* styles to apply to the li tag */ }
```