# CSS set style to the parent of class="something" tag

Tags: css

I have this in my HTML file:

```
<td>
    <div class="something">someText</div>
    <div class="something">otherText</div>
</td>
```

Is there a way in CSS I can set the background of the PARENT of the class named something? In this case, the  tag?

Here is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       function MyMethod(sender, eventArgs) {
           if (condition) {
               app.set_cssClass("MyClass");
           }
           $('.MyClass').parent().css('background', 'url(Images/star.png) no-repeat')
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777379/can-we-set-parent-element-style-from-child-style

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Parent/Ancestor Selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251768/css-parent-ancestor-selector)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this point, no.

However, jQuery can do this quite easily.

`$('.something').parent().css('//WHATEVER')`

In the future, CSS4 will be adopting a **subject** selector, which would do what you need

`$OL > LI:only-child`

The `$` would be used to select the parent or subject of a specific element.

http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject

Comment: I tried this, it says too many characters in character literal.

Comment: @Srcee. That error is usually associated with not escaping characters that need to be escaped. Try changing all the `'` to `"` and then escaping those, eg `""`.

Answer (score 0):

no, as I know there is no parent selector in CSS

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can do it in jQuery

```
$('.something').parent().css('background','<rules>')
```

Where `<rules>` are the CSS rules you want to set for the `background` property.

Comment: I tried this, it says too many characters in character literal.